# Do we need to add the same namespace for -inl.h if we have already did that in .h file

Tags: c++

I am writing down a template in `.h` file and want to put the specific logic inside the `-inl.h`. I am wondering if I need to add the same namespace for my `-inl.h`?

This is my `Test.h` file, in the file I defined a function(not a class).

```
#pragma once

namespace test::mytest {

template <typename T, typename Func>
void log(T& logger, Func func);
} 

#include "Test-inl.h"
```

This is my `-inl.h` file:

```
#pragma once

// Do I really need to put "namespace test::mytest" in -inl.h?
namespace test::mytest {

template <typename T, typename Func>
void log(T& logger, Func func) {
   // some logic here
}
}
```

Seems like I can still build the file when I remove the `namespace test::mytest` from `-inl.h`. I want to know which one is a prefer way?

Comment: When seeing if your template code compiles, be sure you actually instantiate the template. Did you do that? Perhaps add a source file to your question that `#include`s your header then forces an instantiation of your template?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do. Please add more claractions.

Comment: _Hint:_ adding the line `template void test::mytest::log<> (int &, int);` after including the above code forces an instantiation of your template. With this addition, your should find that you can **not** still build the file when you remove the `namespace test::mytest` from `-inl.h`.